# Ads: No fill from ad server. Failed to load ad: 3

Tags: android, admob

I closed admob live ad and then removed the app from background. Now when i launch my app again no ads are displayed. It always gives me the error Ads: No fill from ad server. Failed to load ad: 3.
All the payment is done.But my app is not on play store yet. Before closing the ad , different ads were showing and refreshing.

I have to show 2 ads. This is what I have done in my code

```
        AdView mAdView1 = new AdView(context);
        mAdView1.setAdSize(new AdSize((int) dpWidth / 2, 150));
        mAdView1.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.banner_home_footer));
        ((RelativeLayout) adContainer1).addView(mAdView1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest);


        AdView mAdView2 = new AdView(context);
        mAdView2.setAdSize(new AdSize((int) dpWidth / 2, 150));
        mAdView2.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.banner_home_footer2));
        ((RelativeLayout) adContainer2).addView(mAdView2);
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest2);
```

Hoping to get a solution. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some common causes and how to fix them:

- Make sure you have updated AdMob with your payment details.
- Make sure that the ads you created in AdMob are banner ads.
- Check your AdMob dashboard to see the status of your ads, are they
  active?
- Verify you used the correct Ad Unit Id.
- Give it 24 hours, it can take time for an ad to become active in your region.

**You can run TEST ADS from Admob just by inserting this ad unit id:**

- Banner: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
- Interstitial: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712